# Prefix preserving hash function

Tags: hash, prefix

I am looking for a hash function `f()` whose outputs can preserve the prefix of the inputs. The detailed requirements are as followings.

1. `f()` takes variable-length bit strings as input and outputs bit strings;
2. assume `a` and `b` are bit strings and `a` is a substring of `b`, then `f(a)` is also a substring of  `f(b)`;
3. the length of the output bit string should be smaller than the input bit string.

Any idea?

Comment: I'm certainly no expert here, but isn't the whole idea of a hash function that similar values produce wildly different outputs?

Comment: no, that's not my intention. I care about the prefix preserving property more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be no such hash function that meets your criterion.

Suppose you have such hash function Hash that preserves prefix, then answer these questions:

(1) Hash("a") =? It could be anything, right?

(2) What about Hash("xa")=? to preserve the prefix, it has to be
|Hash("xa")-Hash("a")| + Hash("a")

(3) What about Hash("yxa")=? similarly as (2), it has to be
|Hash("yxa")-Hash("xa")| + |Hash("xa")-Hash("a")| + Hash("a")
So the hash will always have longer lengh than the original.